# Reproducing atoi() without external functions

Tags: c, char, int, data-conversion, atoi

I am looking to reproduce the behaviour of the `atoi()` function without using any other functions such as `strtonum()`. I don't really understand how to convert a `char` or `char *` to int without it being converted to the ASCII value instead. I am doing this in C, any suggestions?

Comment: If your system is using [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii), then the characters in the `char` elements already *are* in ASCII. And for digits the actual encoding doesn't matter, as the C specification says that all digits *must* be consecutive, no matter the encoding. From that information, and a look in the linked ASCII table, you should hopefully be able to figure out how to get e.g. `1` from `'1'`.

Comment: Basic understanding of the decimal numbering system would be good to have as well.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude not required as the answer required is for the conversion of Integer values not float or double.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou By "decimal numbering system" I do not mean floating point values, I mean how the numbers are based on `10` and how you can multiply (and divide) single digits by `10`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow I'm slow. A lot of people replied... BTW, This is my simple example with sign detection. It returns the first parsed part of the string if it encounters an invalid char:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_atoi(const char* input) {
  int accumulator = 0, // will contain the absolute value of the parsed number
      curr_val = 0, // the current digit parsed 
      sign = 1; // the sign of the returned number
  size_t i = 0; // an index for the iteration over the char array 

  // Let's check if there is a '-' in front of the number,
  // and change the final sign if it is '-'
  if (input[0] == '-') {
    sign = -1;
    i++;
  }
  // A '+' is also valid, but it will not change the value of
  // the sign. It is already +1!
  if (input[0] == '+')
    i++;

  // I think it is fair enough to iterate until we reach 
  // the null char...
  while (input[i] != '\0') {
    // The char variable has already a "numeric"
    // representation, and it is known that '0'-'9'                                 
    // are consecutive. Thus by subtracting the
    // "offset" '0' we are reconstructing a 0-9
    // number that is then casted to int.
    curr_val = (int)(input[i] - '0'); 

    // If atoi finds a char that cannot be converted to a numeric 0-9
    // it returns the value parsed in the first portion of the string.
    // (thanks to Iharob Al Asimi for pointing this out)
    if (curr_val < 0 || curr_val > 9)
      return accumulator;

    // Let's store the last value parsed in the accumulator,
    // after a shift of the accumulator itself.
    accumulator = accumulator * 10 + curr_val;
    i++;
  } 

  return sign * accumulator;
}


int main () {
   char test1[] = "234";
   char test2[] = "+6543";
   char test3[] = "-1234";
   char test4[] = "9B123";

   int a = my_atoi(test1);
   int b = my_atoi(test2);
   int c = my_atoi(test3);
   int d = my_atoi(test4);

   printf("%d, %d, %d, %d\n", a, b, c, d);
   return 0;
}
```

It prints:

```
234, 6543, -1234, 9
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot.

Comment: Just one more question, please can you explain the "offset" '0', what is it?

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but does it basically change the ascii value to "input[i]"'s ascii value -  '0''s ascii value so that the value will be between 0 and 9 depending on what number is at input[i]?

Comment: Let's think in ASCII values. Char '5' is in ASCII table 53, while '0' is 48. This means '5' - '0' = 53 - 48 = 5 (that is actually the char 'ENQ', but we cast it to the int 5)

Answer (score 3):

Implementation of `atoi` considering your system uses `ASCII` would be something like (keeping in mind that the number can be negative also)

```
int catoi(const char *string)
{
    int res = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if (*string == '-')
    {
        sign = -1;
        string++;
    }
    if (*string == '+') string++;

    while (*string >= '0' && *string <= '9')
    {
        res = res * 10 + (*string - '0')
        string++;
    }
    return (sign < 0) ? (-res) : res;
}
```

Comment: I have to admit that it is more elegant your use of pointer with respect to my index...

Answer (score 2):

Try using this code from the reference page: [Write your own atoi()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/)

```
// A simple C program for implementation of atoi
#include <stdio.h>

// A simple atoi() function
int PersonalA2I(char *str)
{
    int res = 0; // Initialize result

    // Iterate through all characters of input string and
    // update result
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        res = res*10 + str[i] - '0';

    // return result.
    return res;
}

// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    char str[] = "123456";
    int val = PersonalA2I(str);
    printf ("%d ", val);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of downvoting you could have edited my answer. What is the difference if I write C or C++.. Now I changed C++ to C.. run it the output will be same..

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi Do not take me otherwise.. I am not mad at you.. I sorry.. I must be grateful to you for making me realize the mistake... thank you. :)

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can convert `char` or `char*` as below:

```
int myAtoi(char *str)
{
    int dec = 0, i=0;

    for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        dec = dec*10 + str[i] - '0';
    return dec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly from [Brian W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie: The C Programming Language](https://books.google.sk/books/about/The_C_Programming_Language.html?id=161QAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y):

```
/* atoi: convert s to integer */
int atoi(char s[])
{
    int i, n;
    n = 0;
    for (i = 0; s[i] >= '0' && s[i] <= '9'; ++i)
    n = 10 * n + (s[i] - '0');
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Upvoting, but citing The Book is like cheating... it is not fair :)

Comment: Old resources are bad, `int atoi(char s[])` will hide the fact that it's the same as `int atoi(char *s)` from a non-*expert* programmer who might end up using `sizeof(s)` erroneously. Also, in terms of good design this function should have the following signature `int atoi(const char *const string)`, and finally calling it `atoi()` is bad.

Comment: @MatteoRagni - Thanx for upvoting. I agree with you, but why reinventing the wheel? It would be more unfair *without* link to the source, pretending that it is my code.

Comment: @MarianD Because the reason for this exercise is to check that the student understands how `atoi()` works internally, so it's an exercise for you, not a task for a project, where surely reinventing the wheel means losing money

Comment: @MarianD Sorry, I cannot give you a second upvote for the brilliant comment... even if you deserve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Another small one which can be used with long ACSII strings:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

long long int my_atoi(const char *c)
{
    long long int value = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    if( *c == '+' || *c == '-' )
    {
        if( *c == '-' ) sign = -1;
        c++;
    }
    while (*c >= '0' && *c <= '9') // to detect digit == isdigit(*c))
    {
        value *= 10;
        value += (int) (*c-'0');
        c++;
    }
    return (value * sign);
}

int main () {
   char test1[] = "1234567890123456789";
   char test2[] = "+7654312345678901234";
   char test3[] = "-932112345678901234";
   char test4[] = "9A123123456789012";

   long long int a = my_atoi(test1);
   long long int b = my_atoi(test2);
   long long int c = my_atoi(test3);
   long long int d = my_atoi(test4);

   printf(" %lld\n %lld\n %lld\n %lld\n", a, b, c, d);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 1234567890123456789
 7654312345678901234
 -932112345678901234
 9
```